# Flex styles are not working correctly using Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm making a movie website and I have a component folder for my header, but my "flex" is not working.

**header.tsx**

```
function Header() {
    return (
        <header>
             <div className="flex items-start space-x-2 md:space-x-10">
                <img src= "doctorstrange.jpeg"
                width={100}
                height={100}
                className="cursor-pointer object-contain"
                />

            <ul className="hidden space-x-4 md:flex">
                <li className="headerLink">Home</li>
                <li className="headerLink">Movies</li>
                <li className="headerLink">Videos</li>
                <li className="headerLink">FAQ</li>
                <li className="headerLink">Pricing</li>
            </ul>
          </div>

            <div>
                
            </div>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header
```

**global.css**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
 
/*body, header*/

@layer base{
    body{
        @apply bg-[#141414] text-white;

    }
    @layer components {
        .headerLink {
            @apply cursor-pointer text-sm font-light text-[#e5e5e5] transition duration-[.4]
            hover:text-[#b3b3b3];
        }
    }
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Header from '../component/header'

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Pcarimovie</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Header/>

    <main className=""> 

{/*Banner*/}
      <section>
{/*Row*/}
{/*Row*/}
{/*Row*/}
{/*Row*/}
{/*Row*/}
{/*Row*/}
      </section>
      
    </main>
    
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default Home
```

[this is the actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqmk5.png)

[I want to make a navigation bar that can popup like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X17Bv.png)

Hopefully someone can help me on my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: What does `md:` do?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "flex not working"? What are you expecting, what is the actual result?

Comment: @Konrad `md:` applies the style only for viewports with a width above 768px. See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

Comment: sorry i have change it but on the row 4 the actual coding is this <div className="flex items-start space-x-2 md:space-x-10"> and the "flex" style is not working